# Config file in C# with a simple syntax?

Tags: c#, wpf, app-config

I'm building a C# (WPF) application and I would like to use a simple configuration to define the file paths.
The purpose is for the user to be able to read and/or modify the configuration file easily and without having to learn any complicated syntax (or boilerplate), and to do it using a simple text editor.
I've been reading about the App.config file and from what I understand it is really complicated to modify by hand.

In the past in Windows and in Linux (even today) there were very simple Key=Value files that are exactly what I'm used to - however I see that C# doesn't have any builtin support for INI file reading/parsing.

Can an App.config file be modified easily by a user that isn't familiar with the syntax? If not is there any easy alternative?

Comment: Can _any_ file be modified easily by a user not familiar with it.  If your users are not that advanced, perhaps you should be handling configuration in your UI.

Comment: I'm sure there are libraries for parsing INI files. You could look into other formats as well such as JSON or YAML.

Comment: Since you've got a fairly powerful programming language at hand, implementing your own way of handling .ini files isn't such a burden. see : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1966/An-INI-file-handling-class-using-C

Comment: I'm going with James Thorpe on this. don't expect your users to be comfortable with mucking about in config files where they could do a lot of things wrong. provide them with en easy-to-follow GUI to change settings / preferences.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I think that Key=Value is simpler than XML syntax. However since XML syntax is ubiquitous I'm willing to accept it - as long as it's without any predefined boilerplate text you have to add.

This is obviously a matter of my experience with config files, but I really think it is self-evident that that is the simplest syntax.

Comment: @TimothyGroote As someone who has done that in apps that he has not coded many times, I beg to differ :)

Comment: @TomM as someone who understands software development, that probably sets you apart from most people who will be using your software ;)

Comment: @TimothyGroote I didn't know software development at the ages\ of 10-15, still was editing config files back then though (not to mention what happens in Linux).

Answer (score 2):

For ease of editing, and to remove the complexity of the file as a whole, you can split the appSettings section out to a separate file, referenced from app.config...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <configSections>
      <!- stuff in here -->
    </configSections>
    <appSettings configSource="myCustomisableSettings.config" />
  </Configuration>
```

The separate file should look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<appSettings>
  <add key="FirstPathKey" value="FirstPath" />
  <add key="SecondPathKey" value="SecondPath" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: I think this is close to what I'm after. Can sections be used here as well (like an INI file)?

Answer (score 1):

For this situation, either using the `app.config` or `web.config` there is an `appsetting`'s section that can contain key/value pairs for storing information such as file paths etc that are easily modifiable and readable:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
       <add key="myFilePath" value="pathToFile" />
    </appSettings>
....
</configuration>
```

you can add as many sections within the `appSettings` as you need

Comment: The user has to know about the appsettings tag and configuration tag. I'm talking about writing a file from scratch (say I move the app) without having all sorts of predefined strings that I have to add (like an INI file).

I really don't want to ignore things. That's what makes files complicated to handle.

Comment: You asked for `a simple configuration to define the file paths` and `the user to be able to read and/or modify the configuration file easily` does this not fit the situation nicely?

Comment: I don't think so because it would be hard to write from scratch (if you know the property names) - you have to use boilerplate text.

Answer (score 0):

The App.config file is easily modified. The below is a standard App.config with a custom value.

```
<!-- Start Ignore here -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
    </startup>

  <!-- End ignore here, the below is what you want -->
  <appSettings>
    <add key="myCustomPath" value="C:\Path\To\Something"/> <!-- The user can edit this value -->                   
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

As you can see all the user has to do is change the `value` under the `appSettings` node. It's that simple.

Then to access the value (in your code) all you have to do is call the [`ConfigurationManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myCustomPath"];
```

Comment: See my comment to Ric.